# Install Android application silently Over-The-Air like Google Play does

Tags: android, android-install-apk, device-admin

I need to install apk file without any user prompt like Google PlayStore does.
I know this question has been asked many times but still i didn't found any solvable answer.
I am just installing app from my sdcard and i tried following way,

```
public void getInstall(Context context) {


        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Demo.apk");
        Uri mPackageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        ApplicationManager appMgr = null;

        try {
            appMgr = new ApplicationManager(context);
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        int installFlags = 1;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        Method method = null;

        try {
            method = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                    "installPackage",
                    new Class[] { android.net.Uri.class,
                            android.content.pm.IPackageInstallObserver.class,
                            Integer.TYPE, String.class });
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String installerPackageName = "com.myapp.demo";
        PackageInstallObserver observer = appMgr.new PackageInstallObserver();

        try {

            method.invoke(pm, new Object[] { mPackageURI, observer,
                    installFlags, installerPackageName });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error `Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` even though i added this permission in my manifest file.

**My device is not rooted and i want it to do without rooting** , In many answers i found that it is not possible as per security reason they are not allowing but if it is possible with PlayStore and [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRyb2lkbG9zdCJd) app then why not with us?

Please i need help if it is possible !

Thank you,

Comment: It can't be said often enough: On an Android system, the user is supposed to be in charge. This rule would be violated if what you want were possible. So don't waste any time on such thoughts.

Comment: Thnx @ClassStacker but can you explain how slient installation works with AndroidLost app

Comment: people who giving negative votes please take some time for comment also

Comment: Okay sorry to have asked. Please don't take it personal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My device is not rooted and i want it to do without rooting

This is not possible on Android for third party apps. Google Play is able to do it because it is installed to `/system/app` instead of `/data/app`. If you can convince any OEM or ROM maker to have your app on the system partition, you can utilize the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission, as that is only granted to system apps.

In any case, this is an Android anti pattern. If you were allowed to arbitrarily install apps without user consent, it would be a serious security hole, and the user would no longer be in charge of the device.

Comment: realy thnx for reply.. then what abt AndroidLost app.. they are also providing slient installation..

Comment: @NiravDangi Android Lost doesn't seem to have a silent installation. It is installed through google Play...

Comment: Yes you are right, its using GooglePlay.. thnx

Comment: one more query.. FDroid is also having this feature and i think its not using googleplay.. please check http://f-droid.org/

Comment: @NiravDangi Still not a silent installation. You download the apk to your device and manually install it.